# Sql 2008 exceptionally slow in Vista 64

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, vista64

Our database server is a SQL 2008 server.

My colleagues all have XP service 2 installed with Sql 2008 Management studio and they have absolutely no performance issues.

I however am running Vista x64 (Ultimate) and when I open the 2008 Management studio it's impossibly slow. It takes almost 25 seconds to just connect to the database, so when I run certain portions of our code against the database I more often than not get timeouts.

Everything else on this machine is running like a dream! Is there an issue with SQL2008 on Vista x64 communicating with SQL2008 on a Windows 2003 Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I have my problem while asking the questions.

Vista has a TCP/IP auto tuning feature. By following this tutorial: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/72308-auto-tuning-tcp-ip-receive-level.html I disabled it and now everything runs like a dream!